# 'Font not defined' in Tkinter application freezed by cx_Freeze

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I have freezed a Tkinter-using GUI Python 3.4 app with cx_Freeze and when I tried to run it, I was presented the following error:

```
NameError: name 'font' is not defined.
```

When I remove all references to font from my code (i. e., if I don't set ttk Label fonts anywhere In the code), it works just fine and the exe runs nicely. I have checked the library.zip archive created by the freeze script and it does contain the *font.pyc* file in the tkinter directory.
This is what my *setup.py* file looks like:

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
import tkinter

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("rocnikovka.py", base=base)]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "Number evolution",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter", "tkinter.font"], "includes": ["tkinter", "tkinter.font"]}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "Rocnikovka",
    executables = executables
    )
```

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: I have also tried making an executable out of the script with py2exe but ended up with the same result. Seems like a problem with tkinter rather than with cx_Freeze.

UPDATE #2: I import tkinter and ttk in the script like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
```

I have a few fonts defined in the script, like this one:

```
font_title = font.Font(family = "Exo 2", size = 20, weight = "bold")
```

which I then use as the *font* parameter of *ttk.Label* objects.

This all works just fine when run as a script in IDLE.

Comment: try running it with packages = [], excludes = [], cx-freeze finds tkinter fine with me using python3.4

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I keep getting the same error, though.

Comment: mm without seeing all the code its hard to try/say much. I'm guessing it is not an import error as you have a name error not an import error. Font is not loaded unless you call import tkinter.fontt, Does the code run fine as a script?

Comment: @Arden Yes, it does run just fine as a script, with all the fonts I've set rendering properly. I added some relevant code snippets to the original post. When I remove all font property settings from the script, it runs just fine as executable, too.

Comment: are you also doing an import tkinter.font? i get NameError: name font is not defined if i just do the two imports that you put in your update, there could be reasons the error only surfaces after compiling

Comment: I am not, I assumed that doing from tkinter import * is sufficient. I am going to try that when I get to my computer, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: i always thought so too, its a feature of packaging, the creator can decide what gets imported automatically and what doesn't, good luck!

Comment: Works like a charm. Wow, after those few evenings I spent trying to get it to work… thank you VERY much!
I'll add this solution as the answer so that it might help someone others, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Arden, I was able to get it to work adding an explicit *font* sub-module import:

```
from tkinter import font
```

Works perfectly good now.

Comment: could you figure out the reason it didn't throw the error when running it as a script? That sort of error should have surfaced much earlier.

Comment: Well, the only explanation I seem to have is the one you have mentioned - that cx_Freeze chooses what submodules to import, while Python itself does what one would expect it to.

Comment: …and yet it just imports the whole tkinter module. I don't know if that makes sense, but maybe those executable-making programs, like cx_Freeze and py2exe, take from … import * to mean that they should just import top-level contents of the module and ignore submodules?

Comment: You are mistaken, try doing this, from tkinter import *, print(font), you will find it gives an error.

Comment: I have just tried that. I got <module 'tkinter.font' from '...\\Python34\\lib\\tkinter\\font.py'>.

Comment: im using python 3.4.3 downloaded from the python.org website, windows 7